# Solidity: How to get "floor" of a floating value?

Tags: solidity, contract-design

I'm aware that Solidity doesn't support double and floating values.

I'd like to know if there's any way, in Solidity, to get the floor of a division, like: floor(x/2), where x can be any arbitrary "uint" value? so we can get: floor(5/2)=2;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solidity uses integer division, which is equivalent to floored division.

In solidity, `5/2 == 2`

---

**Note**: Workaround for integer literals feature of solidity

You can try `uint b = uint(5)/2;`

Solidity is [trying to help you](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#rational-and-integer-literals) to not make mistakes.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I tried in Remix; but it's not working!

Comment: What's not working? What result do you get? What code are you using, etc.

Comment: I tried: uint b= 5/2; and also  int cc= 5/2;

Comment: Try `uint b=uint(5)/2;` . Sometimes solidity tries to help you to not make mistakes https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#rational-literals

Comment: Thanks, it works now. It'd be nice if you could add your last comment to the answer.

Comment: Division on integer literals used to truncate in Solidity prior to version 0.4.0, but it now converts into a rational number, i.e. 5 / 2 is NOT equal to 2, but to 2.5.

Comment: this answer is not up to date anymore. it seems now 5/2 == 2.5 and not anymore 2

https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/types.html#rational-and-integer-literals

Comment: What's the current way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2):

In solidity > 0.4.0 (until current version 0.8.x) the solution is like this:

In case of integer literals, you need to type at least one integer explicitly:
`uint x = uint(5) / 2; x == 2`. Otherwise you will get TypeError.

In case of variables, it's automatic:
`uint a = 5; uint b = 2; uint c = a / b; c == 2`.